# Function Parameters Causing Stack Overflow?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, stack-overflow

When I first coded this function, I used a whole lot of global vectors and objects and it worked just fine. Recently I improved my code so that it passes objects and vectors by reference and value but now I get a stack overflow as soon as my program calls this function. I know that the problem lies in the parameters. I updated a few of my other functions to use parameters rather than global objects and global vectors as well and they work just fine. If I had to take a guess I would say the error is caused by too many occurrences of the parameters within the function, but what do I know.
It is a very large function but i will include a sample of it:

```
void armorDisplayText(mainmenu mainmenu1, armorshop &armorshop1, std::vector<textDisplay> &textDisplayArray16, std::vector<textDisplay> &textDisplayArray17, textDisplay textDisplay16, textDisplay textDisplay17)
{
if (armorshop1.firstitem)
{
    if (!armorshop1.armor1displayed && armorshop1.armor1)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor1displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand1string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor1cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor2displayed && armorshop1.armor2)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor2displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand2string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor2cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor3displayed && armorshop1.armor3)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor3displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand3string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor3cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor4displayed && armorshop1.armor4)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor4displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand4string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor4cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor5displayed && armorshop1.armor5)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor5displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand5string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor5cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor6displayed && armorshop1.armor6)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor6displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand6string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor6cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor7displayed && armorshop1.armor7)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor7displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand7string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor7cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor8displayed && armorshop1.armor8)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor8displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand8string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor8cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor9displayed && armorshop1.armor9)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor9displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand9string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor9cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor10displayed && armorshop1.armor10)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor10displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand10string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor10cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor11displayed && armorshop1.armor11)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor11displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand11string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor11cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor12displayed && armorshop1.armor12)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor12displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand12string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor12cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor14displayed && armorshop1.armor13)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor14displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand13string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor13cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor13displayed && armorshop1.armor14)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor13displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand14string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor14cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor15displayed && armorshop1.armor15)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor15displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.offhand15string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor15cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor16displayed && armorshop1.armor16)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor16displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead1string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor16cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor17displayed && armorshop1.armor17)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor17displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead2string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor17cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor18displayed && armorshop1.armor18)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor18displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead3string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor18cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor19displayed && armorshop1.armor19)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor19displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead4string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor19cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor20displayed && armorshop1.armor20)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor20displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead5string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor20cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor21displayed && armorshop1.armor21)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor21displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead6string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor21cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor22displayed && armorshop1.armor22)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor22displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead7string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor22cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor23displayed && armorshop1.armor23)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor23displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead8string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor23cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor24displayed && armorshop1.armor24)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor24displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead9string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor24cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor25displayed && armorshop1.armor25)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor25displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead10string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor25cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor26displayed && armorshop1.armor26)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor26displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead11string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor26cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor27displayed && armorshop1.armor27)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor27displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead12string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor27cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
    else if (!armorshop1.armor28displayed && armorshop1.armor28)
    {
        armorshop1.firstitem = false;
        armorshop1.armor28displayed = true;
        textDisplay16.text.setString(mainmenu1.knighthead13string);
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(100, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
        textDisplay16.text.setString(std::to_string(armorshop1.armor28cost));
        bounds = textDisplay16.text.getLocalBounds();
        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(380 - bounds.width, 110);
        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);

    }
}
}
```

the actual function is much longer than this but it's consistent with whats shown here.

Here's how the function is called:

```
armorDisplayText(mainmenu1, armorshop1, textDisplayArray16, textDisplayArray17, textDisplay16, textDisplay17);
```

and here is the error I get:

```
First-chance exception at 0x04465BE7 in SFML.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00922000).
```

Comment: If the question is, supposedly, about a stack overflow due to function parameters, then why exactly do you believe it's useful to post pages and pages of the function's body, that can't be compiled anyway because the definition most of the clsases being used is not provided?

Comment: I think you are calling with wrong params? the counts doesn't match.

Comment: it doesn't have to do with the call, it has to do with the use of the actual parameters

Comment: I just don't understand why i'm getting a stack overflow when vector textDisplayArray and class object textDisplay are not global but instead passed as parameters

Comment: The two most likely causes of this error: Infinite recursion, or creating gigantic arrays in local variables or parameters.  I see neither of these in the code above.

Comment: @RyanBemrose Well, instances of `mainmenu` and `textDisplay` are in fact being passed by value. For all we know, they may contain gigantic arrays.

Comment: what can I add to clarify this question , im not sure why it's getting downvoted

Comment: read the first comment to understand why it's getting downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you pass some of the parameters (mainmenu1, textDisplay16, textDisplay17) by value rather than by reference.

These parameters may contain huge data in them (i.e. a string of millions characters, or a list of million items).  This also can be due to a bug.

On a side note, your coding style is horrible.  Your function repeats the same lines many times.  Instead your should make the repeating set of actions another function.